# Quiero que una funcion de un script se repita en cada card que se imprime

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Quiero que una funcion de un script se repita en cada card que se imprime (la cantidad de veces que se imprime esta condicionado por un foreach), el script funciona perfectamente en el primer card, pero en el resto no realiza ninguan accion, me seria de mucha ayuda que me aconsejaran que puedo hacer. Gracias

como se ve en la imagen cuando hago click en el boton act el primer "card" me devuleve un texto, pero cuando intento los mismo con el resto no realizan ninguna accion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    <div class="row">

    <?php


        $sql=$pdo->prepare("SELECT motivos.id as mot_id, motivos.nombre as mot_nom, motivos.imagen as mot_img from motivos");
        $sql->execute();
        $res=$sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);



    ?>

    <?php foreach($res as $resp) { ?>

        <div class="col-4 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
            
            <div class="card">
                

                <div class="card-body">

                <div id="primera">
                    insertar nombre: <input id="nombre">
                </div>
                <button type="button" onclick="hacer()" id="boton">act</button>



                <p>dato</p>
                <!input type="text" value="" name="respa" id="respa">

                <?php foreach($res as $resp) {?>
                <div id="resp"></div>
                <?php } ?>

                </div> 
            </div>  <!--cierre de Card-->
        </div>
    <?php } ?>


</div>
```

```
<script> 
    function hacer(){
    var a =null,b=null,c=null;

    a=document.getElementById("nombre").value;
    b=document.getElementById("resp");

    b.innerHTML="El nombre es "+a;

   }
</script>
```

Comment: Saludos. Estas asignando el mismo valor de `id` en todos los elementos y en la función siempre haces referencia a `nombre` y `resp` cada `input` y `div`(el div donde tienes id=resp) cambiales el `id` en cada iteracción; y lo pasas como parámetro a la función.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso te ocurre porque el valor de 'id' debe ser único en todo el documento. Personalmente haría ese código javascript para que recoja el input más cercano dentro de su contenedor para hacerlo reutilizable. Pero sin ánimo de complicar la existencia, simplemente cambiaría el foreach así:

```
foreach($res as $num => $resp)
```

y en el  lo cambiaría por esto (y hacer lo mismo con el div id="resp_"...:

```
<input id="nombre_<?php echo $num; ?>">
```

Y lo mismo para la respuesta. No entiendo porqué haces un foreach dentro de otro foreach si únicamente se ve una respuesta? Quizás eso puedas evitarlo. De manera que cada input tendrá un id único como debe ser. Después, a tu función javascript hacer() le pondría el id directamente. así:

```
<button type="button" onclick="hacer('nombre_<?php echo $num; ?>', 'resp_<?php echo $num; ?>')" id="boton">act</button>
```

y ya por último, en la función ponerlo así:

```
<script> 
function hacer(targetId, respId){
var a =null,b=null,c=null;

a=document.getElementById(targetId).value;
b=document.getElementById(respId);

b.innerHTML="El nombre es "+a;

   }
</script>
```

Comment: El div `resp` también repite ID y falta incluir el segundo parámetro para la función en el evento `onclick`

Comment: muchas gracias, me fue de mucha ayuda